# Handle event on return to page after BrowserTabActivity is closed in flutter

Tags: flutter, redirect, azure-ad-b2c, state-management

First of all this is my first post on stack overflow so I'm not sure exactly how much detail to go into so bare with me :)

I am implementing Azure B2C on an Android/iOS flutter app and I am having issues redirecting users to a home page once they've logged in. I'm new to flutter and I have no idea how to trigger/capture an event when user returns to the page.

Scenario: User opens the app and is taken to the login page, they click a button which opens a browser window using BrowserTabActivity specified in Manifest, on successful authentication the browser window closes and the user stays on the login page with the login button.

How do I trigger something on successful authentication to push the user to the next page?

For B2C auth I'm using flutter_azure_b2c v0.0.9. Authentication process login in and out works fine the only issue I have now is the redirect.

Thanks!

I tried redirecting the users from didUpdateWidget override but it doesn't even trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I had to register a callback for POLICY_TRIGGER_INTERACTIVE in my initState override. Now when the user is successfully authenticated it will redirect back and hit this method.

```
    AzureB2C.registerCallback(B2COperationSource.POLICY_TRIGGER_INTERACTIVE,
    (result) async {
  if (result.reason == B2COperationState.SUCCESS) {
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => const HomePage(title: 'Home Page')));
  }
});
```